# Force trait to be implemented by an Object

Tags: scala, object, traits

how do I force a trait in scala to be only extendable by objects(not classes, traits, etc.)?

I have the following constellation:

```
trait Outer { self: SomeOtherClass =>
  def member: Inner.type = Inner

  /* some other methods... */

  trait Inner { iself =>
    def parent: self.type = self
    /* other methods... */
  }
}
```

My Question is: How can I enforce that the inner trait has to be implemented by an object(like object Inner extends Inner{...})?

I want every class implementing Outer to have an inner object which carries some state + the possibility to get the inner from the outer and vice versa.

Best regards,

Jochen

edit:

Example:

```
// compiles
class C extends Outer {
  object Inner extends Inner { ... }
}

// doesn't compile
class C extends Outer {
  class Inner extends Inner { ... }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `object MyO extends Outer` ?

Comment: [edited question with example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Singleton` self type:

```
trait Outer {
  def member: Inner
  /* other methods... */
  trait Inner { self: Singleton =>
    def parent: Outer.this.type = Outer.this
    /* other methods... */
  }
}

class OImpl extends Outer {
  // Note that OImpl's subclasses can't override member this way
  // You could also do private[this] object member0 extends Inner
  // and override lazy val member = member0 to restore overridability
  // The laziness of object and lazy val mean that member0 won't be created
  // if a subclass doesn't use it.
  override object member extends Inner {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding a method with an object? Btw. the Singleton-thing is new to me, but after reading the doc this seems to be the right way. Going to test it right away..

Comment: @HTNW
If we do `private[this] object member0 extends Inner` then compiler says: 
"Error: private object member0 escapes its defining scope as part of type OImpl.this.member0.type".

Comment: @DmytroMitin that's because of type inference. Doing that infers `member: member0.type`, but `member0` cannot escape outside `OImpl`. Give a type explicitly as `member: Inner = member0`.

Comment: @fxk8y `def` can be overridden with `val`, `lazy val`, `object`, or `var`. `Singleton` is a supertype of singleton types. Types like `x.type` `this.type` etc. are subtypes of it.

Comment: @HTNW Getting following error with above example `Illegal inheritance, self-type OImpl.this.member.type does not conform to Singleton`

Comment: @Kaushal Cannot reproduce on any of 2.13.1, 2.12.11, 2.11.12, or 2.10.7. You should probably update Scala.

Comment: @HTNW, I am using scala 2.11.12 with Intellij. And as you mentioned, If I run with Scala repl, it works fine. Not able to understand, where is the issue?

Comment: And is this the right import `import scala.Singleton`?

Comment: @Kaushal That's the right import, but you shouldn't need to import it, since everything in `scala` is already imported by default. It works for me both in the REPL and if I put it into a file and use `scalac` on it. I'm not sure what IntelliJ is doing. Try restarting it, or maybe hit the compile button. I think IntelliSense can get out of sync with reality sometimes.

Comment: @HTNW, It's weird. In the editor, it shows compile error but when I execute it, it completed successfully.

Comment: Can you please tell me the jar file name on which `Singleton` trait is present? I have looked in scala-library, scala-compile, etc. None of them have a class file for this.

Comment: @Kaushal There is no class file. It's a compiler builtin, just like `Any`, `AnyVal`, `Nothing`, etc.